# Crystal Reports Viewer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2010, I've installed Crystal Reports, but on my form, I cannot find the Crystal Reports Viewer in the toolbox. Is there something special I need to install or activate in Visual Studio in order to have access to that?

Comment: Sounds like you've just installed the runtime for Crystal Reports rather than the development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi take a look at this post here i think it will help you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0be5c56d-2ac4-4827-ab72-643580c2fc64/how-to-enable-crystal-report-viewer-in-visual-studio-2010?forum=vbpowerpacks.

Change your .net version in project settings to not use the "Client Profile" version of .net

Comment: I was trying to find that. Where do I find these properties?

Comment: Go to Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework.  Change that from client to full.